# Any music players with folder browsing for ubuntu?

Tags: music, audio-player

I am looking for a music player with folder browsing capabilities. I want the folder list on the left side and the all the music files on the right side.

Decible, Amarok - ok they are fine, but i am seeing both the files and the folders on the left side. I don't want that I need the folders on the left and when I click on the the files should be displayed on right.

Any player with the above feature ??? and a small equalizer would be great to have along with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Guayadeque](http://guayadeque.org/):**

[image]

Installation:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install guayadeque
```

**[Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/):**

[image]

Installation:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

Answer (score 0):

[Exaile](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/exaile) i think that will do that
http://exaile.org/screens/ - screenshots
[gmusicbrowser](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gmusicbrowser) is pretty good, it has several layout options and a equalizer in the options